# assign values to a big matrix in R

Tags: r, latitude-longitude, apply, ff

I have a matrix object, named `location`, with three columns(`ID`, `latitude`, `logitude`) and 18,289 rows:

```
#      ID    latitude     longitude  
#  320503    31.29530     120.5735  
#  310104    31.18852     121.4365  
#  310115    31.22152     121.5444  
#  110105    39.92147     116.4431
```

I want to calculate the Haversine distance between each ID. In the package `geosphere` the function `distm()` can create the symmetric distance matrix, but its dimension is 18289 by 18289. However, `R` reported the error that it `cannot allocate vector of size 2.5 Gb`.

Similarly, with the `ff` package,

```
data.distance.ff <- ff(0, dim = c(18289, 18289))
```

produces no errors, but when I assign values to the `ff` matrix, `R` produces errors come again.

```
data.distance.ff[1:18289, 1:18289] <- distm(location[, 2:3]
```

> Error: cannot allocate vector of size 2.5 Gb
>       In addition: Warning messages:
>       1: In matrix(0, ncol = n, nrow = n) :
>       Reached total allocation of 2047Mb: see help(memory.size)
>       2: In matrix(0, ncol = n, nrow = n) :
>       Reached total allocation of 2047Mb: see help(memory.size)
>       3: In matrix(0, ncol = n, nrow = n) :
>       Reached total allocation of 2047Mb: see help(memory.size)
>       4: In matrix(0, ncol = n, nrow = n) :
>       Reached total allocation of 2047Mb: see help(memory.size)

I can verify this error with:

```
data.distance.ff[1:10000, 1:10000] <- distm(location[1:10000, 2:3]
```

And then get this error:

> Error: cannot allocate vector of size 772.1 Mb.

My questions are:

1. Is my code for assigning values to the `ff` matrix object wrong? Should I be using something special to assign values to an `ff` object instead?
2. Can`ff` objects handle the storage requirement?
3. Can I use another method to calculate the distance using an apply function that does not involve loops? I know the function `distm()` produces a matrix twice as large as needed because it is symmetric.
4. Are there any other methods for handling with the big data? The `bigmemory` package does not appear to work on my Windows computer.